# Error When submit comment for the second post in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I creating a blog in this blog feed there are posts and for each post there are comments, So my problem when I submit a comment for the first post is submitting successfully but when I try to submit a comment for the second post or third it doesn't submit

My comments Form

```
class PostCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
class Meta:
    model = PostCommentIDF
    fields = {'post', 'content'}
    widgets = {
        'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'rounded-0  form-control', 'rows': '1', 'placeholder': 'Comment', 'required': 'True', })
    }
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    PostCommentIDF.objects.rebuild()
    return super(PostCommentForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My comments view

```
  @login_required
def add_comment_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('action') == 'delete':
            id = request.POST.get('nodeid')
            c = PostCommentIDF.objects.get(id=id)
            c.delete()

            return JsonResponse({'remove': id})
        else:
            comment_form = PostCommentForm(request.POST )
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                user_comment.author = request.user
                user_comment.save()
                result = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')
                user = request.user.username


                return JsonResponse({'result': result, 'user': user})
        return JsonResponse({'result': "No action took"})
```

My comment form in home page template

```
                   <form id="Postcommentform" class="Postcommentform" method="post" style="width: 100%;">
                      {% load mptt_tags %}
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        
                                    <select class="d-none" name="post" id="id_post">
                                        <option value="{{ video.id }}" selected="{{ video.id }}"></option>
                                    </select>
                                          <div class="d-flex">
                                    <label class="small font-weight-bold">{{ comments.parent.label }}</label>
                                    {{ comments.parent }}
                                    {{comments.content}}
                                <button value="Postcommentform" id="Postnewcomment" type="submit"  style="color: white; border-radius: 0;" class="d-flex justify-content-end btn btn-primary">Post</button>
                              </div>
                  </form>
```

### Update

My comment Model

```
class PostCommentIDF(MPTTModel):

   post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
   parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
   author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   content = models.TextField()
   publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Post Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    photo_article = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_poster_filepath)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I use Ajax for submet the comment, When I submit comment for first post this shows `{result: "comment", user: "user1"}`  but when I submit comment for any diffrent post except the first one this shows `{result: "No action took"}`

#### How I can let the user submit comment to any post not just for the first one

#### Edit

```
    myCommentForm = document.getElementById("Postcommentform")

$(document).on('click', '#Postnewcomment, #Postnewcommentinner', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var button = $(this).attr("value");

  var placement = "Postcommentform"
  if (button == "Postnewcommentform") {
     var placement = "becomm"
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url "video:addcomment_post" %}',
    data: $("#" + button).serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success: function (json) {
      console.log(json);

      $('<div id="" class=" p-2" style=""> \
        <div class="d-flex bd-highlight mb-3">\
         <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"><img src="{{request.user.profile_image.url}}" alt="" class="rounded-circle bd-highlight" width="30" height="30"> ' + json['user'] + '</div> <div class="ml-auto p-2 bd-highlight">Posted: Just now!</div> \
         </div>\
         <div>' + json['result'] + '</div> \
         </div>'
).insertAfter('#Boo');
         
         document.getElementById("Postcommentform").reset();
       },
       
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {

    }
  });
})


function myFunction(id) {

if (document.contains(document.getElementById("Postnewcommentform"))) {
  document.getElementById("Postnewcommentform").remove();
}

 var a = document.getElementById(id);
 a.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',
'<form id="Postnewcommentform" class="Postnewcommentform py-2" method="post"> \
             {% csrf_token %}\
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><h2>Reply:</h2><div><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="formExit()"">Close</button></div></div> \
            <select name="parent" class="d-none" id="id_parent"> \
                <option value="' + id + '" selected="' + id + '"></option> \
            </select> \
            <label id="id_content" required="" for="id_content">Content:</label> \
          <textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control" required="" id="id_content"></textarea> \
          {% csrf_token %} \
          <button type="submit" value="Postnewcommentform" id="Postnewcommentinner" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button> \
        </form>');
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is the request body, is the template?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the request body, is the template?

Comment: instead of that ```<select>``` use a text input with ```name="post"``` and test whether it work.

Comment: Did you mean  this `<input>`

Comment: yes and put a valid post id in it as value.

Comment: @Sumithran The same problem happens, I can add comments to just the first post and I can't with the second one

Comment: got to the network tab in the chrome dev tool and see the request body when you click the button and check it is not passing the same post id when you change the post id in the text input..

Comment: I figure out thing when I am in first post and I add inside the input the second or third post id it send successfully

Comment: It shows `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: In Form data it shows `post: 6` that the same id of the first post, It happen when I submit comment for post 4 or 5 it shows `post: 6`

Comment: @Sumithran It is problem-related to Ajax

Comment: yeah, maybe, show your ajax code.

Comment: I added my ajax code